# send email testing fake data in browser

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do email testing send fake data for partner registration. I create another route and another method in `Backend\DevelopentController.php` and in `web.php` to run in the browser. when I run in the browser I get an error Class

> 'App\Helpers\General\MailHelper\Route' not found

below is my code:

**web.php**

```
namespace App\Helpers\General\MailHelper; 

use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\DevelopmentController;
use App\Helpers\General\MailHelper;    

Route::get('/email/register-partner',  'Backend\DevelopmentController@register_partner');
```

**controllers\Backend\DevelopmentController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
namespace App\Helpers\General\MailHelper;

public function register_partner() {
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'fake name',
        'companyName' => 'berjaya Corp',
        'contact__person' => '01202132',
        'email' => 'partner@gmail.com'
    );

    (new MailHelper)->partner_registration('partner@gmail.com', $data);
}
```

**MailHelper.php**

```
namespace App\Helpers\General;

public function partner_registration($email,$data) {
    $lMessage1 = '<p>Dear <strong>'.$data['name'].'</strong>,</p>
    <p>Thank you for registering with us. You are just one step away to register successfully,
    please attach a document as reference to be related with your nature of business. Click <a href="'.url('agency/upload/info').'/'.$data['resetCode'].'"> here </a>
    to attach.</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Motor dealer : business name card</li>
        <li>Insurance agent / agency : Agent Identity Card or business name card</li>
    </ol>
    <p style="color:#000;">
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li>Company Name : '.ucwords($data['companyName']).'</li>
            <li>Contact Person : '.$data['contact_person'].'</li>
            <li>Contact  : +60'.$data['contact'].'</li>
            <li>Email : '.$data['email'].'</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <p>
        You will receive another email from us after your registration has been approved.
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>Thank You, <br/>Example Partner Program Administration</p>
    <p>Website <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a><br/>
    Tel : +6014243242</p>
    <p style="color:grey;font-size:8pt;">IMPORTANT NOTICE OF DISCLAIMER</p>
    <p style="color:grey;font-size:8pt;">
        The information in this email and any attachments is intended only for the person or entity to which it addressed and may contain confidential and/or privileged material. Any review, retransmission, dissemination, or other of, taking of any action in reliance upon, this information by persons or entities other than the intended recipient is prohibited. If you are not the intended recipient, please delete the message and any attachments and notify the sender of misdelivery
        Any views expressed by an individual within this e-mail do not necessarily reflect the view(s) of example Sdn. Bhd. and shall include but not limited to all of its subsidiaries and associated companies
    </p>';

    $subject = 'Your online registration has been submitted successfully';
    $params['data'] = $lMessage1;
    $params['to_email'] = $email; //required
    $params['template_type'] = 'markdown';  //default is view
    $params['template'] = 'emails.app-mailer'; //path to the email template
    $params['subject'] = $subject; //optional
    $params['from_email'] = config('mail.from.address');
    $params['from_name'] = config('mail.from.name');

    try {
        sendmail($params);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::alert('Partner Registration User Email failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: mention laravel version also so it might help someone to answer

Comment: I use laravel 7

Comment: You have two `namespace` definitions in `DevelopmentController` also

Comment: as suggested by @apokryfos.remove namespace from DevelopmentController 
 . this one namespace App\Helpers\General\MailHelper; and add  use App\Helpers\General\MailHelper;

Comment: also `web.php` should not have a namespace.  [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7.x/routes/web.php) is how it usually looks like. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` is at the top and you can put any other `use` clauses you need, but no namespace

Answer (score 2):

1st step
Now you have to replace this line

```
use App\Helpers\General\MailHelper;
```

into

```
use MailHelper;
```

now run and check it

2nd step

also replace this line

```
(new MailHelper)->partner_registration('partner@gmail.com', $data);
```

into

```
(new \MailHelper)->partner_registration('partner@gmail.com', $data);
```

then run command `composer dump-autoload`

i hope you got your solution .